# How to Make A Combination of Lists of A List in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, combinations, python-3.5

> I do not know whether to call it *combination* or *permutation*, so the question can be edited regarding your comment in question.

I have a list as below:

```
[
    ["a"],
    ["b", "c"],
    ["d", "e", "f"]
]
```

I want this to output as:

```
[
    "abd",
    "acd",
    "abe",
    "ace",
    "abf",
    "acf"
]
```

My first priority is to make this with built-in tools or by hand, not with other scientific modules. However, if there is no way, scientific modules might be used.

---

## Environment

- python 3.5.1

Comment: Did you try [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the comments, you could use `itertools.product`. Or you could implement a simple recursive method:

```
def combine(lists, index=0, combination=""):
    if index == len(lists):
        print combination
        return
    for i in lists[index]:
        combine(lists, index+1, combination + i)

lists = [
    ["a"],
    ["b", "c"],
    ["d", "e", "f"]
]

combine(lists)
```

Comment: You could do this, but why re-invent the wheel? This is a classic `itertools.product` problem.